# imagePath of camera picture in onPictureTaken?

Tags: android, camera, save

I want to take camera pictures programmatically and save them in the gallery. *MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(ContentResolver cr, **String imagePath**, String name, String description)
* seems nice. But how do I get:

- from the **byte[] picture** in the *onPictureTaken()* callback,
- to the **String imagepath** which the *insertImage()* requires?

More generally, how does one do this in simplest way:

```
onPictureTaken(byte[] picture, Camera cam){
//save picture to file in gallery
}
```